# Extracting specific venue categories from Foursquare API using Python code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, foursquare

I'm trying to extract Foursquare venues data for the city of Baltimore, but only want to get specific categories (specifically things like supermarkets, grocery stores, etc.) How do I search for specific venue categories and return only venues of a specific type?

The language I'm using to extract the data that I want (from Foursquare API) is Python, and I'm working from Jupyter Notebooks. I want to limit my venue search to the following categories, however:

Farmers Market (4bf58dd8d48988d1fa941735)
Grocery Store (4bf58dd8d48988d118951735)
Organic Grocery (52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b45)
Supermarket (52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b46)

I started with just one category and I don't get an error in the kernel where the code is run.  When I move on to the next kernel, though, I get an error of the following type:

'TypeError: string indices must be integers'

What is this code telling me?

```py
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=2000, LIMIT=50, categoryId='52f2ab2ebcbc57f1066b8b46'):

    venues_list=[]
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)

        # create the API request URL
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}&categoryId={}'.format(
            CLIENT_ID, 
            CLIENT_SECRET, 
            VERSION, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            radius, 
            LIMIT,
            categoryId)

        # make the GET request
        results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['venues'][0]['id']

        # return only relevant information for each nearby venue
        venues_list.append([(
            name, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            v['venue']['name'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
            v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
    nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighborhood', 
                  'Neighborhood Latitude', 
                  'Neighborhood Longitude', 
                  'Venue', 
                  'Venue Latitude', 
                  'Venue Longitude', 
                  'Venue Category']

    return(nearby_venues)
```

The bit of code above runs fine in that it returns no errors.  It's the code below that presents problems for me.

```py
balt_markets = getNearbyVenues(names=balt_crime_df['Neighborhood'],
                                   latitudes=balt_crime_df['Latitude'],
                                   longitudes=balt_crime_df['Longitude']
                                  )
```

Here's the error output:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-b1d736ce8ff2> in <module>
      2 balt_markets = getNearbyVenues(names=balt_crime_df['Neighborhood'],
      3                                    latitudes=balt_crime_df['Latitude'],
----> 4                                    longitudes=balt_crime_df['Longitude']
      5                                   )

<ipython-input-142-8aee194c1f65> in getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius, LIMIT, categoryId)
     27             v['venue']['location']['lat'],
     28             v['venue']['location']['lng'],
---> 29             v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])
     30 
     31     nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])

<ipython-input-142-8aee194c1f65> in <listcomp>(.0)
     27             v['venue']['location']['lat'],
     28             v['venue']['location']['lng'],
---> 29             v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])
     30 
     31     nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `intent=browse` and comma separated categories ids, e.g.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?categoryId=50aa9e094b90af0d42d5de0d,530e33ccbcbc57f1066bbff3,530e33ccbcbc57f1066bbff9,4f2a25ac4b909258e854f55f&intent=browse&client_id={{CLIENT_ID}}&radius=30000&v=20171031&ll=51.51453,-0.12574&client_secret={{CLIENT_SECRET}}&limit=30
```